# ASP.NET bug iframe hides textboxes?

Tags: asp.net, html, xhtml, iframe

Well here is my problem: I have a table with an iframe in the first cell and then some rows below I have some textboxes and buttons. But as long as the iframe is on the page the buttons and textboxes do not show up.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<Iframe/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="password">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

to demonstrate below is the same code and it hides the textbox

---Table---

---Table ends here---

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: <Pedantic>No need for the apostrophe in the title</Pedantic>

Comment: If there's no runat="server" in the code, then it could be an HTML bug, but not an ASP.NET bug for sure. And which browser?

Comment: well a </iframe> does solve the problem but i think a <iframe/> should be enuf? opera and ie buggs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make sure that you are closing the iframe tag properly

```
<iframe src="xyz.aspx" id="ifr" name="ifr" ></iframe>
```

closing tag-> "`</iframe>`"

Comment: but shouldent <iframe src... /> do it?

Answer (score 1):

This is no ASP.NET bug! Not even an HTML bug.

James_Smith is right, the `<iframe>` element is not self-closing, and requires a separate closing tag.